# AWS SAM Template: Issue mapping S3 events to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I've followed the AWS SAM documentation for hands-on learning experience and have reached this particular section: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html

Above page in the documentation explains how to map the S3 events to any resource and I've done something similar on my local machine. My local template below.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  CreateThumbnail:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 60
      Policies: AWSLambdaExecute
      Events:
        CreateThumbnailEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref testBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*

  testBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Now, when I build and deploy above SAM template, while a new S3 bucket is getting created, the 'object creation' event is not mapped to the Lambda function created. PSB screenshot.

[image: Screenshot showing that S3 events are not mapped]

I haven't found any articles or blogs on this error (probably, I'm doing a silly mistake here)

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What was your SAM cli command?

Comment: `sam build` followed by `sam deploy --guided`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that for some reason, the AWS Lambda console is not showing the trigger event but the mapping is successful. I've also validated by uploading sample image to the bucket which triggered the lambda.

The event mapping can be seen in the properties section of the S3 bucket created.

S3 test bucket created -> Properties -> Events

[image: S3 bucket properties showing the created events]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `AWS::Lambda::Permission` to your `Resources` as described in this [AWS SAM Github issue](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/300#issuecomment-510847259)

```
  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyFunction.Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: 's3.amazonaws.com'
      SourceAccount: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}
      SourceArn: !GetAtt MyBucket.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

First create bucket where you plan to save packaged code

```
aws s3 mb s3://youtbucketname
```

After `sam build`
go for

```
sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket <yourbucketname>
```

Comment: It's giving me the below error
`Error: Unable to upload artifact CreateThumbnail referenced by CodeUri parameter of CreateThumbnail resource. S3 Bucket does not exist.`

Can you tell me why you suggested the above change in command? What does it do? It's expecting the S3 bucket to be present before the actual execution of template.

Comment: Sorry I took long. Creating an S3 bucket beforehand defeats the purpose of SAM.

I just realized that although the Lambda console is not showing the triggers setup in the UI(a bug?), the events have actually been mapped. I've validated it by putting an image in the S3 bucket and thus triggering the lambda function.

**TL;DR** : The original code in my question worked.